# Python failing to recognise number above 1000

Tags: python

```
magicnumber = 2000 ;

for x in range(10000):
    if x is magicnumber:
        print(x,"Is the Magic Number")
        break
```

I need assistance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 4):

You need to replace `is` with `==`. And you need to read this for more understanding: [Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)

```
magicnumber = 2000 ;

for x in range(10000):
    if x == magicnumber:
        print(x,"Is the Magic Number")
        break
```

Output:

```
(2000, 'Is the Magic Number')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if x is magicnumber:
```

is the same as

```
if x is 2000:
```

which returns false, therefore that condition is never met

```
if x == magicnumber:
```

is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 1):

```
magicnumber = 2000

for x in range(10000):
    if x == magicnumber:
        print(x,"Is the Magic Number")
        break
```